# What does trying to remember a moment when I’d felt more uncomfortably American. mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

Context : Young woman (American) is (reluctantly because she didn't want to have tea but didn't want to be rude) having tea with an old woman (Irish). the old woman asked her if she would pour them tea.

Book setting : Ireland.

> “Will you pour?” she asked primly.
> “Yes. Yes, I’d be glad to,” I
> stammered, **trying to remember a moment when I’d felt more
> uncomfortably American.** I mentally scrambled for the etiquette, trying
> to remember what came first.

What does this **trying to remember a moment when I’d felt more uncomfortably American.** mean? Is she trying to remember the time when she felt more uncomfortable being American that this time she has to pour tea?

[What the wind knows, Amy Harmon.](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/40407141-what-the-wind-knows)

Comment: This translates pretty easily to Spanish, if that is your language.

Comment: I'm sorry. My native is Thai...

Comment: By the way,  it's "milk first"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is she trying to remember *a* time when she felt more uncomfortable being American *than* this time she has to pour tea?

Yes.

It means

> There was probably never a time when she felt so uncomfortably American.

which means

> She felt uncomfortably out of place because of lack of knowledge regarding Irish etiquette, such as how to serve tea.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!